# How can I get the most recent result from a group of records in postgresql, where the relevant data is stored as a JSON array?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have two postgresql tables:

- `services`, which has a `name` and `description`, as well as a foreign key `ofsted_item_id`
- `ofsted_items`, which has an `inspection` column that contains a JSONB array of objects

The inspection JSONB column contains data that looks like this:

```
[
  {"date": "2006-06-19", "judgement": "Satisfactory"}, 
  {"date": "2009-01-22", "judgement": "Satisfactory"}
]
```

**I'd like to get the name and description from the services table, along with the most recent judgement.**

So far, I've been able to break out the JSON arrays into nice, neat columns, and join it with the second table :

```
SELECT
    ofsted_items.id, 
    name,
    description,
    this_inspection->>'judgement' AS judgement,
    this_inspection->>'date' AS date
FROM ofsted_items

LEFT JOIN services 
ON ofsted_items.id = services.ofsted_item_id,

LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(inspection) AS this_inspection
```

This works perfectly.

But sadly I'm failing at the last hurdle: I can't find a sensible way to **only return the most recent (ie. "biggest" value in the date field).**

So far I've tried:

- `UNIQUE`
- `GROUP_BY and MAX()`, which doesn't seem to do anything, perhaps because the date field is JSON?

I've also considered sub-selects, but with that approach I don't see how I could actually show the nicely presented judgements from the JSON column.

For the sake of the question, let's assume I am powerless to change the structure of the data.

Comment: Most recent value per *what*?  Per item id?

Comment: Exactly. each service/ofsted_items has lots of inspections, and each one has a date. we only want to see the most recent inspection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `distinct on`.  If you want one row per `id`, then:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (i.id) i.id, s.name, s.description,
       this_inspection->>'judgement' AS judgement,
       this_inspection->>'date' AS date
FROM ofsted_items i LEFT JOIN
     services s
     ON i.id = s.ofsted_item_id
ORDER BY i.id, this_inspection->>'date' DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `distinct on`. I think you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (oi.id)
    oi.id, 
    s.name,
    s.description,
    x.this_inspection ->> 'judgement' AS judgement,
    x.this_inspection ->> 'date' AS date
FROM ofsted_items oi
LEFT JOIN services s ON oi.id = s.ofsted_item_id,
LEFT JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(s.inspection) AS x(this_inspection) ON 1 = 1
ORDER BY oi.id, x.this_inspection ->> 'date' DESC
```